# Limiting developer access to git repository for a website and how to deploy it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, capistrano, web-deployment

I am considering taking on a new developer for my rails based website but, because I do not know them, I do not want them to have complete read access to my code.  I only want them to be able to read and write to one directory.

**Requirements:**

I would also like them do be able to deploy their updates/changes.

Both myself and the developer use windows so symbolic linking is not a good idea...

I currently use capistrano to deploy the website but will use vlad or anything else that will work...

**Background Reading**

So, I have been reading about submodules, subtrees (apenwarr's git-subtree and the subtree merge strategy), giternal, piston, braid, etc, etc and I am completely flummoxed!  Any help that can be provided would be greatly appreciated!

**My current thoughts**

I don't think that **submodules** are the right choice here because:

1) I would like to make as few changes as possible to the main repository

2) i) The developer would need access to the main repository to notify it of submodule changes... which defeats the purpose of making them work with a submodule.

ii) I could create a master repository that would reference the divided sections of the website but I have no idea how to do this or if it would even work.

**Subtrees**

If I understand them correctly, someone can work on the subtree and commit to it as if they had full access to only that part of the master repository.  At first glance this seems to make them just exaclty what I need - especially since the master repository can reference the current HEAD of a subtree by default and doesn't need manual updating. Unfortunately I can't see how I would deploy the website with subtree nor can I tell if this is really want I want.  There is a lot of conflicting opinion about submodules, subtrees etc and it is difficult to sort through it.

Thank you very much for your time reading this and any help that you can offer!

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't hire developers you don't trust? :) If you're concerned about code getting leaked or similar stuff, that should be covered by contracts and such. Just my $.02.

Comment: In an ideal world that would be true but I don't have the resources to sue anyone if they steal my code. :(  I would like to develop the working relationship gradually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Submodules:
2) send you "pull request", by email or web-based system.

Comment: Because of this response I used submodules.  I created repositories on my server which are updated automatically when a commit is made.  This allows the submodule and primary repository to stay in sync with each other.  Of course, it means that there is a commit in the main repo for each submodule commit but at least the code is partitioned now.
I also deploy the website automatically after every commit to the submodule.  This is still done via capistrano.